# Cloudbees Flow DevOps Insight server will not install on RedHat 8

Tags: devops, cloudbees

I am trying to install CloudBees Flow Devops Insight Server on Red Hat 8 but every time I try it I get this:

```
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Set installer log file (77523D0C-BA20-4A50-85CA-3068EE88C25A) action completed in 00m00s
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Executing action Detect docker environment (81AE405F-2A19-4D0A-AD73-DF979A19F0F7)
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Docker container has been not detected by /proc/self/cgroup
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Detect docker environment (81AE405F-2A19-4D0A-AD73-DF979A19F0F7) action completed in 00m00s
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Executing action Load commander library (B9B46DA9-28A9-459F-8A14-E1443CD933E5)
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Load commander library (B9B46DA9-28A9-459F-8A14-E1443CD933E5) action completed in 00m00s
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Executing action Load EF Reporting Server library (6D9F01E1-EF66-46FA-8642-290F363DD9FC)
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Load EF Reporting Server library (6D9F01E1-EF66-46FA-8642-290F363DD9FC) action completed in 00m00s
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Executing action Load Elasticsearch API (27931D6F-FFBB-45E9-A73B-0F874168C771)
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Error while loading required packages: failed to load library "/installkitvfs/lib/tls/tcltls.so": could not load file from temp location: couldn't load file "/tmp/tclP68qMf": /tmp/tclP68qMf: cannot open shared object file: Operation not permitted
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - failed to load library "/installkitvfs/lib/tls/tcltls.so": could not load file from temp location: couldn't load file "/tmp/tclP68qMf": /tmp/tclP68qMf: cannot open shared object file: Operation not permitted
    while executing
"load [file join $dir tcltls.so] Tls"
    (lambda term "{dir} {
                if {{shared} eq "static"} {
                        load {} Tls
                } els..." line 5)
    invoked from within
"apply {{dir} {
                if {{shared} eq "static"} {
                        load {} Tls
                } else {
                        load [file join $dir tcltls.so] Tls
                }

                set tlsTclInitScript [file join $..."
    ("package ifneeded tls 1.7.22" script)
    invoked from within
"package require tls"
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Executing action group Cancel Actions (F6959579-28D0-401F-AC59-7BB03948B8FF)
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Executing action Display installer log file location (F9554BA4-9356-44C8-BC90-AB89268BB0B6)
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Display installer log file location (F9554BA4-9356-44C8-BC90-AB89268BB0B6) action completed in 00m00s
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Executing action Cleanup temporary directory (2E6EBA28-09E1-43B2-993A-F43F912A5BEB)
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Executing action Clean files from temporary directory (9280CBAD-2B7C-40EE-AD91-FD2625A65150)
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Executing action Clean files from temporary directory (9280CBAD-2B7C-40EE-AD91-FD2625A65150)
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Clean files from temporary directory (9280CBAD-2B7C-40EE-AD91-FD2625A65150) action completed in 00m00s
06/06/2023 14:49:31PM - Cleanup temporary directory (2E6EBA28-09E1-43B2-993A-F43F912A5BEB) action completed in 00m00s
```

I have tried using the --temp option on the installer to point it to a different directory but it obstinately insists on using /tmp. I did install tcltls with yum, but I cannot find providers for installkitvfs.

Anybody run into this before? How did you fix it?